# Using Simple Search with Kaminari Pagination Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, kaminari

I am trying to apply pagination to my rails app using Kaminari.  I am also incorporating a simple search form based on the [Railscast Episode #37](http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form).  When I try to apply the kaminari page and per methods I get the error 'undefined method page'. Below is the code I'm using.

posts_controller.rb

```
def index
  @posts = Post.search(params[:search]).page(params[:page]).per(2)
end
```

post.rb

```
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, conditions: ['title || body LIKE ?', "%#{search}%"], order: "created_at DESC")
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end
```

index.html.erb

```
<%= paginate @posts %>
```

When I remove the pagination the search works fine.  When I remove the search the pagination works fine.  I just can't seem to use them both and have the code function properly.  Please advise if there is something in my code that I am missing that is causing this not to work properly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your case, you are returning array object from the search method not  **ActiveRecord::Relation** object.

```
 find(:all, conditions: ...) # find method will return an array object.
```

Add check in your controller,

```
def index
  @posts = Post.search(params[:search])
  if @posts.class == Array
    @posts = Kaminari.paginate_array(@posts).page(params[:page]).per(10) 
  else
    @posts = @posts.page(params[:page]).per(10) # if @posts is AR::Relation object 
  end
end
```

Kaminari pagination with an array https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#paginating-a-generic-array-object

for ActiveRecord::Relation object, checkout this http://railscasts.com/episodes/239-activerecord-relation-walkthrough

Comment: It would be a better answer if it had the explanation... "Give a man a fish and you feed him for a day. Teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime."

Comment: @Aaron I just updated my answer more descriptive as suggested by Agush

Comment: @Santosh I accepted the answer, but could not upvote it due to lack of reputations.  Thanks for the detailed explanation...I appreciate knowing the reason and not just the solution.

Comment: In Rails 4 you'd use a "where" clause instead of "find". Where will return a scope, so you won't have to differentiate between Array and Scope.